# Flutter Web Error: Target dart2js when build html renderer

Tags: flutter, dart

**I have run the web with:**

> flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html

**Because I work by network image and It worked, Now I want to create a build for the web and i use:**

> flutter build web --web-renderer html --release

**But I get this error in terminal:**

```
Target dart2js failed: Exception: Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..51: 52
#0      _StringBase.[] (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:260:41)
#1      buildJsInteropBootstrap.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/js_backend/js_interop_analysis.dart:31:58)
#2      new _GrowableList.generate (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:133:28)
#3      buildJsInteropBootstrap.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/js_backend/js_interop_analysis.dart:30:35)
#4      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#5      Maplet.forEach (package:compiler/src/util/maplet.dart:210:12)
#6      buildJsInteropBootstrap.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/js_backend/js_interop_analysis.dart:23:15)
#7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#8      CodegenWorldImpl.forEachInvokedName (package:compiler/src/universe/codegen_world_builder.dart:843:19)
#9      buildJsInteropBootstrap (package:compiler/src/js_backend/js_interop_analysis.dart:21:16)
#10     FragmentEmitter.emitMainFragment (package:compiler/src/js_emitter/startup_emitter/fragment_emitter.dart:788:45)
#11     ModelEmitter.emitProgram (package:compiler/src/js_emitter/startup_emitter/model_emitter.dart:309:45)
#12     EmitterImpl.emitProgram.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/js_emitter/startup_emitter/emitter.dart:196:27)
#13     CompilerTask.measureSubtask (package:compiler/src/common/tasks.dart:181:35)
#14     EmitterImpl.emitProgram (package:compiler/src/js_emitter/startup_emitter/emitter.dart:195:18)
#15     CodeEmitterTask.assembleProgram.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/js_emitter/code_emitter_task.dart:143:26)
#16     CompilerTask.measure (package:compiler/src/common/tasks.dart:66:51)
#17     CodeEmitterTask.assembleProgram (package:compiler/src/js_emitter/code_emitter_task.dart:114:12)
#18     JsBackendStrategy.assembleProgram (package:compiler/src/js_model/js_strategy.dart:353:35)
#19     Compiler.runCodegenEnqueuer (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:485:39)
#20     Compiler.generateJavaScriptCode (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:363:9)
#21     Compiler.compileFromKernel.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:561:7)
#22     CompilerTask.measureSubtask (package:compiler/src/common/tasks.dart:181:35)
#23     Compiler.compileFromKernel (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:528:14)
#24     Compiler.runInternal (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:333:15)
<asynchronous suspension>


Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                             89.8s
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
```

**and i try**

> flutter channel beta

**and I get the same problem**

**Note: i use flutter 2.8.0 channel stable, and all command in this link:**

[enter link description here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/web-renderers)